# how do i calculate a restaurant bill per table

Tags: java, billing

Here is my code:

**Order Class**

```
public class Order {
    private int orderId;
    private int tableId;
    private int quantity;
    private String name;
    private int price;
}
```

**Constructor**

```
public Order(int o, int t, String name, int q, int price) {

    orderId = o;
    tableId = t;
    this.name = name;
    quantity = q;
    this.price= price;
}
```

**OrderList Class**

```
public class OrderList {

    private ArrayList<Order> orderList;

    public OrderList() {
        orderList = new ArrayList<Order>();
    }
}
```

**Populate method**

```
    Order o = new Order(15, 3, "Paan Kiwi", 1, 10.00);

    Order o = new Order(16, 3, "Pasta", 3, 18.00);
```

How do I write a method to calculate the total price of all the Orders from a specific table?

Ignore the bad syntax please :)

Comment: Your question is not very clear. *Total price of each meal per table*? Do you mean the total of all the orders from a single table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you have getters and setters for the fields you have specified. i.e. for the `price` field you should have a `getPrice()` method in the `Order` class. I'm also assuming that you want to programatically specify the `tableId` for the table you want to calculate the bill for.

So if I understand you correctly:

```
public int calculateTableBill(int tableId, OrderList orderList) {
    int billTotal = 0;
    for (Order order : orderList.getOrderList()) {
        if (order.getTableId() == tableId) {
            billTotal += order.getPrice()
        }
    }
    return billTotal ;
}
```

This will loop through all your the Orders and total up the prices of those Orders where the `tableId` is the same as the one passed into the method.

I hope that is helpful to you. Please leave a comment if I didn't understand you correctly and I will adjust my answer :)

Comment: hi, This was exactly what i was looking for. Thank you very much!! youre a lifesaver :)

Comment: No problem. Glad it helped! If you would like to you can click the tick next to this answer to accept it and the up-arrow to upvote it. You will get points for accepting an answer to your question and I will get points for my answer being accepted. :) You can only mark one answer as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make a method that iterates over the orderList and adds up the price of each meal (I assume you already add the orders into the orderList somewhere, and every table has its own orderList):

```
public int calcPrice(int tableId, ArrayList<Order> orderList){
    int sum = 0;
    for(Order o : orderList)
        if(o.tableId = tableId)
            sum += o.price;
    return sum;
}
```

Hope this helps ;)

EDIT: At the moment you store the price in an int, but you use a decimal point. If you store 19.99 in an Int, you would actually store a 19. What you want to do is change "int" to "double". Same would apply for my method then.

Comment: Instead of voting down, or even in addition, please leave feedback why this answer is bad/not helpful.

Comment: I think you got downvote because your answer doesn't answer op  question. Because You are calculating the whole sum in list.. but the OP required 'per table'

Comment: Also you haven't initialized `sum`. You need `int sum = 0;` otherwise the you get a compiler error "Local variable sum may not be initialized."